# Does this “が” mean “but”? What is the difference between 習うと思う and 習おうと思う?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, verbs

I'm not sure my translation for this brief conversation is correct, particularly the last sentence, so would like it double checked please.

> カレン: ニールさんは音楽の学生ですね。
> ニール: そうですが、どうして？
> カレン: バイオリンを**習おうと思っている**んです**が**、いい先生を**知りませんか**。
>
> Karen: Neil you're a music student aren't you?
> Neil: That’s right but why do you ask?
> Karen: Well I've been thinking of learning the violin so do you know any good teachers?

A couple of things:

1. The が in the last sentence is confusing me as I can't see how a 'but' would really fit in.
2. What would be the difference between 習うと思っている and 習おうと思っている?
3. I was initially flummoxed by the 知りませんか but I think it’s a request form question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation is correct.  However, this `が` isn't the "but" one.  It's the "softener" one.  I can't think of a way to translate it (if there even is one), but it's often used to make one's own desires/actions seem less direct and a little more humble.

Ex.

> - 聞きたいことがあるんですが...　→　There's something I'd like to ask you...

---

The difference between `習うと思っている` and `習おうと思っている` is the former would be used to indicate "I think <someone else> will learn" vs. "I'm thinking ***I'd like to*** learn".  `〜（よ）うと思う` is a very common form for expressing a desired, yet uncertain intention.

Comment: Even when used as a softener it's still acting as "but", however the second clause is often omitted in such cases.  A common example of this is when declining an invitation: "I'd love to, but [I really would rather not]..."  It allows people to save face by not having to express unpleasant points.

Comment: You don't say する・習う+と思っている for "I'm thinking of ~~ing". You can say しよう・習おう+と思っている, したい・習いたい+と思っている, する・習う+つもりだ etc...

Comment: 習うと思っている in that context doesn't make sense.
私は習うと思っている basically means "I think you/he/she/they will learn it". when the agent of learning is the speaker himself, it indicates some conditional situation and doesn't mean the speaker actually has intention to learn.

Answer (score 2):

> カレン: バイオリンを習おうと思っているんですが、いい先生を知りませんか。

As written, が is being used as a gentle lead-in.  It's adding a sense of "I'm probably bothering you by asking, but...".

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question regards the last line of Karen.
The alternative English translation of the last line could be:
I've been thinking of learning the violin. By the way do you know any good teacher?
though there is a subtle difference of implications from your translation.

習うと思っている is very different from 習おうと思っている. The former is stating a simple future, like “I will be learning English when I get into the 1st grade of middle school.” The latter is stating your wish / desire like, “ I want (intend / plan) to study French (when I get into college)”

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is correct, but I think the construction  習おうと思っている could be translated literally as 'I'm thinking (to myself): let's learn'. 
習おう is the same construction you would use to suggest doing something. You could for example say 日本語を習おう (meaning: Let's learn Japanese!)

Comment: This is not really correct, in my opinion. 習おうと思っている (and in general volitional form + と思っている) is a way of describing your not very committed plans or intentions. So literal translation is not a proper way of translating that phrase.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you actually translate it literally. Now that I reread my comment that does seem to be my intention though...  
It's just that I have always wondered whether this expression could have originated that way, and thinking of this literal translation helps me remember the proper translation of this construction.